# Disable Horizontal Scrolling of UIScrollView AutoLayout Resizable ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a UIScrollView which is getting resized on runtime according to some conditions. Now i used auto layout properly without using a single constraint extra or less. The first subview of scroll view has leading, trailing, top, bottom and equal width to scroll view and the height of the content view is managed by its inner content which is also changing depending on the runtime condition. Now according to my constraints my content view should not scroll horizontally as i used equal width to scrollview. But its happening. Can anyone suggest what am doing wrong? Here is the images of constraints i have used.

**NOTE:- I have seen the posts on stack where this kind of question answered but my case is different.**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Content `UIView` width should be equal to the width of `UIScrollView`'s superview for instance, not `UIScrollView` itself.

Comment: Could be because `UIScrollView`'s superview (`Description` in your storyboard) has larger width than `UIScrollView`. If this is the case, try wrapping `UIScrollView` in a `UIView` container and apply resizing logic to this container instead of scroll view. Then set content's width equal to this container view, as in my original answer — it won't work with width set equal to scroll view anyway.

Comment: i have tried to set the equal width constraint of content view to the superview of the scrollview which is description view and also i have used your above suggestion of taking another view as superview of scrollview inside description view but the problem is the same. I know the problem is because the size of description view and scrollview is not fixed as i mentioned in question. The width of description view and scrollview will change according to the device width. Without changing those things i want the content only scroll vertically.

Comment: I tried giving width a fixed constraint to width of content view. and it worked but i don't want to fix the width of the content view too.

Comment: Well it should not matter if their frames change, as long as you have that width equality constraint in place, your content view should always be of the same width as this wrapping view, or `Description` — whichever you end up using as a width reference. Assuming you don't change the frames directly, it should work just fine (I tried and it does for me). I would probably double-check console output for autolayout warnings, made sure there are no conflicting constraints you accidentally added, constraints priorities are the way you want them, etc.

Comment: i have no warning, not at design time, nor at runtime. And am not changing the frame. I set proportional width of description view to superview which is main view. in iPhone 5 the width is 300 and in iPhone 6 it increases proportionally and the inner scrollview too as its leading and trailing to description view is 0. I have designed so many complex layouts and all were fine but this one is getting out of my reach. I have tried removing all constraints and adding all again. Nothing worked.

Comment: i solved it...by this `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        let scrollSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)
        scrollView.contentSize = scrollSize
    }`  thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Sounds like a workaround to be honest! My last guess would be that the issue is in the way content is added to the content view — it should be possible to achieve the same thing without explicitly setting `contentSize`, but rather by letting `contentView` to expand to its intrinsic content given a strict width constraint.

Comment: yes it should be possible but when nothing worked this worked. I know what i did is wrong but i will try to achieve this without statically changing the content size when i will get some time.

Comment: @M.K.As you are giving equal width constraints for content View and UIScrollView's superview , there is no need to give trailing constraints to content view , can you please remove  trailing constraints and try it.

Comment: if i remove trailing constraint, its giving me constraint warning. Its necessary for the content because its inside a scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used to 'constraint to margin' option while I am adding constraint from storyboard. When I only add trailing and leading without relative to margin problem solved. I did not give any superview to my UIScrollView.